# Regular Expression for Email with default domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I want to add to a textbox a `regular expression` to let introduce emails only with `@yahoo.com` and `@gmail.com` . All other emails to set to be errors.

I am using `DevExpress` TextBox for `ASP.NET WebForms`. I see that they have a regular expression for email , but not with a certain domain.

Do you know if i can accomplish that? Maybe using a mask or validation.

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" Width="150px" Text="">
    <ValidationSettings CausesValidation="true" Display="Dynamic" ErrorText="*" ValidationGroup="Users">        
      <RequiredField IsRequired="true" />
       <RegularExpression ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
   </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

```
 <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" Width="150px" Text="">
                                                                    <ValidationSettings CausesValidation="true" Display="Dynamic" ErrorText="*" ValidationGroup="Users">
                                                                        <RequiredField IsRequired="true" />
                                                                        <RegularExpression ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+@(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com)$" />
                                                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use another regular expression, for example:

```
^\w+@(gmail\.com|yahoo\.com)$
```

Answer (score -1):

check this one :

```
^([\w\.\-_]+)?\w+@(gmail\.com)|(yahoo\.com)$
```

cool tool for regex : http://regexr.com/

Comment: Why would you allow a dot or dash as the *first* character, but nowhere else in the address? You still miss a large number of allowed characters in the localpart.